# How can you divide verbs into conjugation groups easily?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I have been learning the verb list for the N4 exam but I do not know how to tell the group of a verb. Until now I have memorized them by heart. Nevertheless I still have trouble telling the group of a verb because I can't memorize them all. I wondered whether there is a systematic method of knowing the group of a verb. Could you help me with that?

According to my textbook:

- いきます belongs to group I
- ねます  belongs to group II
- きます belongs to group III

Comment: Only group I verbs conjugate to irrealis form (pre ない form) through -a phoneme. e.g. 行く ik-u → ik-a-nai, 寝る ne-ru → ne-nai, 来る ku-ru → ko-nai.

Comment: As an answerer commented, the -masu form is perhaps the worst verb form to figure out the conjugation group from. Drop it and learn the dictionary forms (iku, neru, kuru) immediately.

Comment: @user4092 Though 学校文法 also gives さ as a 未然形 of する, as in される or させる.

Comment: Then, pre-ない forms only.

Answer (score 13):

First, Group III is the easiest to devide because 来{く}る and する are the only verbs that belong to it. These verbs have each irregular conjugation as you probably know.

---

Then, if the verb ends with another than ''る'', it belongs to Group I.
For example, you can tell which group 行{い}く belongs to, because it ends with ''く'' which is another than ''る''. Yes, ''行く'' belongs to Group I.

---

Next, I'll tell about verbs that end with ''る''.
You have to care the previous vowel to ''る''. 
For example, let's watch a verb ''乗{の}る''. This verb can be written ''noru'' in the alphabet, then the previous vowel to ''る'' is ''o''. 
If the previous  vowel is ''*a*'', ''*u*'', or ''*o*'', the verb belongs to Group I.

---

It's a difficult case for you when the verb ends with ''る'' and the previous vowel to ''る'' is ''*-i*'' or ''*-e*'', e.g. 走{はし}る hash*iru*, 食{た}べる tab*eru*, and 寝{ね}る n*eru*.
 
Most verbs that end with ''i-る'' or ''e-る'' belong to Group II, so it's easier to  memorize verbs that belong to Group I in spite of its feature.

It has been said by rhyaeris, I will mention them again.
The verbs as follows are Group I, however you can't tell which group they belong to only by their dictionary forms.
I dare to give all verbs that I can remember, so there would be some unfamiliar verbs for you.
 - 走{はし}る
 - 入{はい}る
 - 要{い}る いる{LH}   (居{い}る belongs to Group II. いる{LH}) 
 - 煎{い}る　いる{HL}
 - 帰{かえ}る かえる{HLL}   (変{か}える belongs to Group II. かえる{LHH})
 - しゃべる  (It is similar to 食{た}べる, but they belong to another group each other.)
 - 滑{すべ}る
 - 減{へ}る へる{LH} (経{へ}る belongs to Group II. へる{HL})
 - 知{し}る
 - 切{き}る  きる{HL} (着{き}る belongs to Group II.　きる{LH})
 - 散{ち}る
 - 蹴{け}る
 - 練{ね}る ねる{HL} (寝{ね}る belongs to Group II. ねる{LH})
 - 限{かぎ}る
 - 交{ま}じる/混{ま}じる (It's the intransitive verb of 交ぜる/混ぜる that belongs to Group II.) 
 - 過{よ}ぎる  (It has a little similar meaning to 過ぎる and すぎる and よぎる is written in the same kanji, however the two belong to different group from each other.)
 - 焦{あせ}る
 - 競{せ}る
 - 照{て}る
 - 火照{ほて}る
 - かじる
 - 茂{しげ}る
 - いじる
 - いびる
 - なじる
 - うねる
 - くねる (It is usually seen in ''曲がりくねる'')

Memorizing these verbs, you can tell that 走{はし}ります and 走{はし}った are correct, not *走{はし}ます and *走{はし}た, 食{た}べます and 食{た}べた are correct   not *食{た}べります and *食{た}べった because 食べる isn't in the list above though it ends ''*e-る*''.

Comment: I think it's great that you gave a step-by-step process to identifying verb groups, as well as mentioned homonyms that are in different verb groups. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't ある also belong to the irregular verb grouping?

Comment: It's only a 五段. あらず・あります・あるし・あるとき・あれば・あれ

Comment: In classical language, ある belongs to irregular verb because the 終止形 of it is not ある but あり.

Comment: I hope it will be the accepted answer since it is, by far, the most detailed.

Answer (score 7):

Japanese verbs can be divided into three groups (godan verbs, ichidan verbs and irregular verbs). Nevertheless, the -ます form is not the best to tell them apart.

---

Godan verbs (Group I) ends in く、ぐ、う、ぶ、る、ぬ、つ、む、す. Examples are: 行｛い｝く、泳｛およ｝ぐ、買｛か｝う、遊｛あそ｝ぶ、上｛あ｝がる、死｛し｝ぬ、待｛ま｝つ、読｛よ｝む、話｛はな｝す.  There is some overlapping with verb ending in る.I mean that you have to learn the groups of verbs ending in る because 帰{かえ}る is a godan but 変｛か｝える is ichidan.

---

Ichidan verbs (group II) can be divided in two groups (上一段{かみいちだん} and 下一段{しもいちだん}) that is verbs ending in -いる (上｛かみ｝, the name is 上 because if you draw あいうえお vertically い is above え) and -える (下｛しも｝).
Examples are: 寝{ね}る, 食*べる*, 起*きる*. Very often the え/いる part is in hiragana (寝る is an exception to that).

---

Irregular verbs (Group III) are really easy, there are two irregulars verbs する and 来｛く｝る.

Comment: I thought 行く was irregular?

Comment: @Blavius I think 行く is a godan verb.

Comment: @Blavius 行く is only irregular in that it conjugates to 行って, 行った, etc. instead of the expected 行いて, or 行いた, etc.

Comment: @virmaior Strictly, in foreigner parlance, 行く is a "Group I" verb, a godan verb - though still irregular in the 行って form.

Comment: 「行かない」「食べない」「起きない」などの「～ない」の形から何段活用か判断する、っていう方法は使われないんですね。。。（日本語教師検定取って日本語教えてる友達が「ない形はかなり初期に暗記させんねん」って言ってたんですけど…）

Comment: @rhyaeris indeed -- my mistake because i never actually use those categories (prior comment deleted - i never understood why they felt a need to re-invent 一段 vs. 五段 as "group ii" and "group i")

Comment: @Blavius There are a number of other irregular verbs, but they're traditionally lumped into one of the first two categories.  I'm not sure why.

Comment: @snailboat Those verbs are mostly regular and identifiable. One or two irregular conjugations isn't justification for a new class.

Comment: @Nothingatall It's not justification for a *new* class; it's justification to put it into the already existing irregular class.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to add on to 変幻出没's post by clarifying the Group I (godan) verb exceptions - not only do they end in る, **they all end in える and いる, but are actually Group I rather than Group II (ichidan)**.

(Not to say that Japanese should be studied purely for the JLPT, but this information is relevant to your N4 studies: there are a finite number of Group I exceptions you need to know for your test.) **JLPT or not**, most of the basic ones are in the following picture: http://www.kanji-link.com/docs/en_gram_n5_verb_groups.pdf

> There are 10 exceptions listed at the bottom of the picture.
>
> 6 of them are definitely at N5 level: 帰る　要る　切る　知る　入る　走る.
>
> Currently I am studying for N4, and so far out of the other 4 I only know that 喋る is at N4 level.
>
> Of course, it is impossible to predict which words will appear and which definitely won't appear, so feel free to study them all.

Comment: Thank you for 1. fixing the fact that I mixed up the groups' numbers (even if I highly recommend just memorizing godan and ichidan) 2. giving details on the overlapping る ending of godan verbs with ichidan verbs.

Comment: @変幻出没 こちらこそ thank you. Thanks for a great answer below, and for suggesting that じしょ form be used to distinguish verbs.

Answer (score 3):

- **Step 1:** single **漢字 + え/い + る: 一段**
- **Step 2:** one mora single **漢字 + る: 一段**

  - Notes

    - There are only around 90 of verbs following this pattern, and most
      of them compound verbs of 見る and 出る, see the list below
    - This rule was pointed out by Weijun Zhou in comments
- **Step 3:** all other are **五段**

**LIST OF ONE MORA ICHIDAN VERBS**

> 相似る    あいにる    to resemble each other, to resemble one another v1 vi
>
> 相見る・逢い見る   あいみる    to face v1 vi
>
> 仰ぎ見る・仰見る・あおぎ見る あおぎみる   to look upwards, to look up v1 vt
>
> 甘く見る   あまくみる   to not take seriously, to take lightly  v1
>
> 現われ出る  あらわれでる  to appear   v1
>
> 射る いる  to shoot (arrow, bolt, dart)    v1 vt
>
> 居る いる  to be (of animate objects), to exist
> to stay(after the -te form of a verb) verb indicating continuing action or state (i.e. to be ..ing, to have been ..ing) aux-v uk v1 vi
>
> 鋳る いる  to cast, to mint, to coin   v1 vt
>
> 癒る いる  to calm down    uk v1 vi
>
> 色眼鏡で見る いろめがねでみる    to look at things from a biased viewpoint (biassed) v1
>
> 浮び出る・浮かび出る・うかび出る   うかびでる   to surface  v1 vi
>
> 浮かれ出る・浮れ出る うかれでる   to go out in a merry mood   v1 vi
>
> 浮き出る   うきでる    to rise to the surface, to surface
> to stand out (e.g. against a background)  v1 vi
>
> 打ち見る・打見る   うちみる    to glance at, to look at    v1
>
> 訴え出る   うったえでる  to lodge a complaint    v1
>
> 打って出る  うってでる   to launch oneself upon, to make one's debut v1
>
> 生まれ出る  うまれでる   to come into being, to be born  v1 vi
>
> 得る える  to get, to earn, to acquire, to procure, to gain, to secure, to attain, to obtain, to win
> to understand, to comprehend
> to receive something undesirable (e.g. a punishment), to get (ill)to be able to ..., can ...   aux-v v1 vt
>
> おっ魂消る・押っ魂消る    おったまげる  to be very surprised, to be flabbergasted   uk v1 vi
>
> 躍り出る・おどり出る おどりでる   to jump (e.g. to first place), to spring out    v1 vi
>
> 垣間見る   かいまみる   to take a peep at, to catch a glimpse of    v1 vt
>
> 顔から火が出る    かおからひがでる    to be extremely embarrassed, to burn with shame v1
>
> 偏り見る   かたよりみる  to show partiality  v1
>
> 勝ち得る   かちえる    to achieve, to win, to gain, to attain  v1 vt
>
> 着る きる  to wear (in modern Japanese, from the shoulders down), to put on
> to bear (guilt, etc.)   v1 vt
>
> 下卑る    げびる to become vulgar, to coarsen    v1
>
> 心得る    こころえる   to know, to understand, to be aware of, to regard as, to take for
> to consent, to agree   v1 vt
>
> 小洒落る   こじゃれる   to be somewhat stylish, to be somewhat chic col v1 vi
>
> 込み居る   こみいる    to push in, to be crowded   v1 vi
>
> 差し出る・差出る   さしでる    to be forward, to stick one's nose into, to meddle, to be intrusive
> to jut out, to protude, to overhang  v1 vi
>
> 時化る    しける to be stormy or choppy (sea)
> to go through hard times, to be broke
> to be gloomy, to be glum   uk v1 vi
>
> 湿気る    しける・しっける    to be damp, to be moist v1 v5r vi
>
> 下に見る   したにみる   to look down on, to despise, to condescend  v1
>
> しみ出る・染み出る・滲み出る しみでる    to ooze, to exude, to percolate, to soak through    v1 vi
>
> 〆る しめる to total, to sum    v1 vt
>
> しゃしゃり出る    しゃしゃりでる to come uninvited, to crash (a party), to butt in   v1
>
> 洒落る    しゃれる    to dress stylishly
> to joke, to play on words v1 vi
>
> 悄気る    しょげる    to be dispirited, to be dejected, to be disheartened, to lose heart uk v1 vi
>
> 知り得る   しりえる    to acquire knowledge    v1
>
> じろりと見る じろりとみる  to throw a glance   v1
>
> 進み出る   すすみでる   to step forward, to volunteer   v1 vi
>
> 滑り出る   すべりでる   to slip out v1 vi
>
> 退治る    たいじる    to exterminate, to eliminate, to eradicate, to suppress v1 vt
>
> 魂消る    たまげる    to be astonished, to be startled, to be appalled    uk v1 vi
>
> 突き出る   つきでる    to project, to stick out, to stand out  v1 vi
>
> 出来る    できる to be able (in a position) to do, to be up to the taskto be ready, to be completed
> to be made, to be built
> to be good at, to be permitted (to do)
> to become intimate, to take up (with somebody)
> to grow, to be raised
> to become pregnant    uk v1 vi
>
> 出る でる  to leave, to exit, to go out, to come out, to get out
> to leave (on a journey), to depart, to start out, to set out
> to move forward
> to come to, to get to, to lead to, to reach
> to appear, to come out, to emerge, to surface, to come forth, to turn up, to be found, to be detected, to be discovered, to be exposed, to show, to be exhibited, to be on display
> to appear (in print), to be published, to be announced, to be issued, to be listed, to come out
> to attend, to participate, to take part, to enter (an event), to play in, to perform
> to be stated, to be expressed, to come up, to be brought up, to be raised
> to sell
> to exceed, to go over
> to stick out, to protrude
> to break out, to occur, to start, to originate
> to be produced
> to come from, to be derived from
> to be given, to get, to receive, to be offered, to be provided, to be presented, to be submitted, to be handed in, to be turned in, to be paid
> to answer (phone, door, etc.), to get
> to assume (an attitude), to act, to behave
> to pick up (speed, etc.), to gain
> to flow (e.g. tears), to run, to bleed
> to graduate   v1 vi
>
> 届け出る   とどけでる   to report, to notify    v1 vt
>
> 飛び出る   とびでる    to project, to protrude, to pop out (e.g. eyes)
> to jump out, to rush out v1 vi
>
> 道化る    どうける    to jest, to clown (around)  v1 vi
>
> 流れ出る   ながれでる   to flow out, to stream out, to pour out, to gush forth, to leak, to ooze out, to drift away v1
>
> 名乗り出る  なのりでる   to introduce oneself, to announce oneself (e.g. as the person sought), to come forward (e.g. as a witness, with a claim, etc.)  v1 vi
>
> 並み居る   なみいる    to sit in a row, to be present (and lined up)   v1 vi
>
> 滲み出る・にじみ出る にじみでる   to exude (e.g. sweat), to ooze, to seep out
> to reveal itself (of emotions, etc.) v1 vi
>
> 若気る    にやける    to be effeminate, to be a fopto break into a smile, to grin col uk v1 vi
>
> 似る にる  to resemble, to look like, to take after
> to be similar (in status, condition, etc.), to be close, to be alike, to be like    v1 vi
>
> 煮る にる  to boil, to simmer, to stew, to seethe  v1 vt
>
> 抜き出る・抜出る   ぬきでる    to surpass, to outdo, to excel, to stand out, to be outstanding, to be preeminent
> to tower above (the surrounding landscape) v1 vi
>
> 抜け出る   ぬけでる    to slip out, to steal out
> to excel, to stand out v1 vi
>
> 盗み見る   ぬすみみる   to steal a glance, to intercept and read (e.g. other people's email)    v1
>
> 願い出る   ねがいでる   to apply for    v1 vt
>
> 寝る ねる  to lie down
> to go to bed, to lie in bed
> to sleep (lying down)
> to sleep (with someone, i.e. have intercourse)
> to lie idle    v1 vi
>
> 逃れ出る   のがれでる   to scuttle off, to take flight  v1
>
> 望み見る   のぞみみる   to gaze into the distance   v1 vt
>
> 惚気る    のろける    to play up, to speak fondly of, to praise one's spouse  uk v1 vi
>
> 這い出る・はい出る  はいでる    to crawl out of, to creep out of    v1 vi
>
> 走り出る   はしりでる   to run out (e.g. of the room)   v1
>
> 跳ね出る   はねでる    to spring or rush out   v1
>
> 食み出る   はみでる    to jut out (of bounds)
> to be crowded out, to be forced out   v1 vi
>
> 人妻と寝る  ひとづまとねる to sleep with another person's wife v1
>
> 干る ひる  to dry  v1 vi
>
> 嚏る ひる  to sneeze   v1 vt
>
> 吹き出る・噴き出る・吹出る・噴出る  ふきでる    to blow out, to spout out   v1 vi
>
> 巫山戯る   ふざける    to joke, to jest, to kid, to josh
> to make fun of, to laugh at, to play a prank
> to romp, to gambol, to frolic, to frisk, to mess around, to fool around, to screw around
> to neck, to make out   uk v1 vi
>
> 経る へる  to pass, to elapse, to go by
> to pass through, to go through
> to experience, to go through, to undergo  v1 vi
>
> 迸しり出る・ほとばしり出る  ほとばしりでる to gush out, to gush forth, to effuse   v1
>
> 罷り出る   まかりでる   to leave, to withdraw, to appear before v1 vi
>
> 老成る    ませる・マセる to be precocious, to be mature for one's age, to seem grown-up, to seem mature  uk v1 vi
>
> 真似る    まねる to mimic, to imitate    v1 vt
>
> 看る みる  to look after (often medically), to take care of    v1 vt
>
> 見る みる  to see, to look, to watch, to view, to observe
> to look over, to look on, to assess, to examine, to judgeto look after, to keep an eye on, to take care ofto view (e.g. flowers, movie)to try, to try out, to test
> to see that..., to find that... aux-v uk v1 vt
>
> 診る みる  to examine (medically)  v1 vt
>
> 廻る・回る  みる  to go around    v1
>
> 群れ居る・群居る   むれいる    to crowd in, to come together   v1 vi
>
> 申し出る   もうしでる   to report to, to tell, to suggest, to submit, to request, to make an offer, to come forward with information    v1 vt
>
> 萌え出る   もえでる    to sprout, to bud   v1 vi
>
> 夢見る    ゆめみる    to dream (of)   v1 vt
>
> 世に出る   よにでる    to become famous
> to go out into the world, to make one's way in the world, to appear, to be published    v1
>
> 分かれ出る  わかれでる   to branch out, to diverge, to radiate   v1
>
> 湧き出る・わき出る・涌き出る・沸き出る    わきでる    to gush forth   v1 vi

Comment: `人妻と寝る ひとづまとねる to sleep with another person's wife v1` -- Jisho lists it as a single verb, not as a phrase..? もう「寝る」があるからねぇ。。`世に出る よにでる to become famous` これも、一つの「動詞」じゃないような・・・ あと、`飛び出る、届け出る、流れ出る、申し出る...` とか、複合動詞は「XX出る」でまとめたら・・・キリないし。。

Comment: If the Kanji (no 's' here) that goes before -ru correspond to more than 1 moras, the verb is Godan. All the exceptions listed above follows the Kanji(single mora)+ru pattern, and most of them are just complex verbs constructed by Renyoukei and need not be memorized on their own. By the way, 得る is not Ichidan.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the single mora rule. I think the algorithm can be improved then. According to goo https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/25679/meaning/m0u/%E5%BE%97%E3%82%8B/ 得る is 一段.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know what 'group' a verb is in. That's a completely abstract way to think about verbs that is just a made up construct used to explain things in an academic setting.

It really slows you down if you have to stop mid sentence to think about what 'group' a verb is in.

Instead you want to be able to recognize it on the subconscious level and be able to spit out the correct conjugation **without thinking** about it at all.

Japanese is an extremely regular language so this is fairly easy to achieve. It takes some work but the general gist of it is:

There are several different sounds verbs can end In

る、す、む、く、ぐ、ぬ、つ、う、ぶ

And it among the ru verbs there is a separate pattern when there is an 'e' sound before the 'ru' like える.

You don't ever need to think about which groups these are in. Forget about it. It's just not helpful. The easiest way to acquire the natural ability to conjugate verbs without even thinking about which group they are in is to memorize all the conjugations for each of those verbs endings for at least 3 different verbs of each ending. Once you've done it for 3 different verbs with that ending the pattern crystallizes and you begin to internalize it and start using it naturally without thinking about it. Here's a list of [all the major japanese verb conjugations](http://www.verbsmash.com)

Comment: While it's true that it's not answering the question directly, I _can't stress more_ the importance of the first three paragraphs of this answer. I've also experienced that after learning how to conjugate many verbs by pure practice and drilling, you will easily get a feeling and remember how to conjugate new verbs you learn.

Answer (score 1):

I've learned from different textbook approaches and from living in Japan on a language exchange I came up with the following for myself:

1. **Does it end with る**

   - **No?** *Then it's group 1*
   - **Yes?** *Could be group 1 or 2*

If it ends with る then you'll simply have to look it up to see how its conjugated. Use your textbook or an online Japanese verb.

Also, I always thought of it roughly as:

**group 1 conjugation**

- consonant + ～います

  - あるく to あるきます

    - aruk<strike>u</strike> to aruk*imasu*

After a while you'll, through repetition and exposure, *just know* the correct sound of a verb. Good luck!

Comment: Though you have said the conjugation was "roughly" as such, I would like to point out the two cases in which the consonant does change - つ to ち (eg. tatsu, to stand -> tachimasu), and す to し (eg. osu, to push -> oshimasu). :)